# bit data type returns -1

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I am working on a web application in Visual Studio 2010. I am writing and reading to a database table using SQL Server 2008.

I have a database table, `myTable` with a column `myColumn` of datatype `bit`. I write to this column on the web app like so:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = 1
```

This works fine, and using SQL Server Management Studio I can see the column gets updated to **TRUE** as I would expect.

In another part of my web app I query the table like so:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT myColumn FROM myTable"

sqlRdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

While sqlRdr.Read
      myColumn = sqlRdr(0)
End While
```

When I run this query, `myColumn` gets set to -1. How does this happen? According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) a bit is

> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.

and

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

I do not understand how I am getting `myColumn = -1` from this query.

Comment: What is the data type of `myColumn` and how is it defined in your VB.net code?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I believe the OP has stated datatype bit in his question.

Comment: @Mary That’s the data type in the table in SQL Server. I’m asking about the `myColumn` variable in the VB.net code.

Comment: From MS Docs "All conversions from integral or floating-point numbers to Boolean values convert non-zero values to true and zero values to false." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @AaronBertrand The data type of ```myColumn``` was ```Integer``` before I encountered problems. I then changed it to data type ```Boolean``` to work how I expected but was curious of what was going on in the background, hence this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the data for a `bit` column, you are actually getting a 32-bit number, not just a single bit. In that 32-bit number, either EVERY bit is set to 1 or every bit is set to 0. The value 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 when converted to an `Integer` using two's complement is -1, because the first bit is the sign bit.

The problem is that you should not be using `Integer` in your VB code. The ONLY time you should be using 1 or 0 to represent this data is literal values in SQL code. In your VB code, you should be using `Boolean` to represent this data because that what the data is. 1 represents `True` and 0 represents `False` and you will see that if you view the data in SQL Server Management Studio.

That means that here:

```vb
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT myColumn FROM myTable"

sqlRdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

While sqlRdr.Read
      myColumn = sqlRdr(0)
End While
```

that `myColumn` variable should be type `Boolean`. That code should not compile at all anyway because it requires `Option Strict Off` and you should pretty much always have `Option Strict On`. You should not be assigning the `Object` reference you get from the data reader to a variable of type `Integer` or `Boolean`. You should use the data reader to get the data as it's actual type. If you really were getting an `Integer`:

```vb
myColumn = sqlRdr.GetInt32(0)
```

but, as you will doing it properly and using `Boolean`:

```vb
myColumn = sqlRdr.GetBoolean(0)
```

If you ever wanted to save data then you would generally be using parameters, e.g.

```vb
sqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = @myColumn"
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@myColumn", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = True
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I did end up changing ```myColumn``` in the VB code to ```Boolean``` data type so I would get the expected result prior to making this post but I wanted to know why I was getting -1. I think your reference to two's complement pointed me in the right direction and I will try to digest that for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric value of True is -1 ,False is 0

```
Debug.Print(Val(True) & " " & Val(False))
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Bit type is mapped to the .Net System Boolean type (True/False).

Your code,

```
myColumn = sqlRdr(0)
```

is using VB's rules for implicit type conversions. Presumably `myColumn` is an integer type and the Object variable type returned by `sqlRdr(0)` is a Boolean.  VB maps true to a value of -1 and false to a value of 0.

If you were to use `System.Convert.ToInt32` for Boolean to integer conversion, you would receive a value of one (1) when converting a boolean true value.

```
myColumn = System.Convert.ToInt32(sqlRdr(0))
```

Note that if you use VB's preferred `CInt` function, or `Ctype` function, you would also receive a -1 value.

Comment: That is all true but I would suggest that what actually should be done is declaring `myColumn` as type `Boolean` and then using `sqlRdr.GetBoolean(0)` to get the value as a `Boolean`. Given that `bit` columns represent `Boolean` data, there's no good reason to not be using `Boolean` in VB code.